# Yodlee Fastlink Callback Issues

Tags: yodlee

We have been developing with Fastlink off the dev sandbox (while we wait for our private zone and public zone Fastlink keys) and are running into an issue. Callback isn't occurring after a brokerage account is successfully linked to an account. We are, however, receiving a callback to our specified callback URL when we pass invalid keys, or an invalid nonce. Do you know what might be causing this issue?

Answer (score 3):

Since Dev sandbox is for testing , the fastlink's close button has be removed and hence you are not able to go back to call back URL because you need to click on the close buttons to go to call back URL.

In your private and public Zone you will have those buttons enabled and hence you will be able to navigate to call back URL upon completion of link account process.

Comment: Sandbox is for testing.  So how are we supposed to test the callback?

Comment: @sgress454- We do understand the requirement and we are continuously working on enhancing and enriching our Sandbox environment and also we love to have your feedback which will help us improving the sandbox. For now I would suggest you to use the existing functionality within sandbox and finish your rest of the testing in your private zone.

Comment: @Apoorv +1 from me for a close button even in the sandbox as a feature request.  I don't see how it's really protecting anything for Yodlee -- but it's adding risk for me by making the testing impossible, and more urgently it is very definitely confusing the sandbox-based demo I've been showing to the executive team and the UX designer.

Comment: @TimothyJohns - Sure I'll work internally to see what can be done for this.