# What query parameters are passed to the Yodlee FastLink oauth redirect callback on success (close)?

Tags: yodlee

Once the user is finished with the add account flow in FastLink, and clicks the 'close' button, what query string (if any) is passed to the redirect callback URL?

Closely related to, but distinct from, this question:

[Yodlee Fastlink Callback Issues](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24895610/yodlee-fastlink-callback-issues)

Thanks!

-- Tim

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Now that we're out of the sandbox, I can answer my own question for the next person who might encounter this.  On the user closing FastLink, the callback url was passed parameters like this:

error_code=0&status=success&account_id=12345678